# How to make substr_replace match the whole string

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $titledb = array('经济管理','管理','others');
    $content='经济管理是我们国的家的中心领导力，这是中文测度。';

    $replace='<a target="_blank" href="http://www.a.com/$1">$1</a>';
    foreach ($titledb as $title) {
        $regex = "~\b(" . preg_quote($title) . ")\b~u";
        $content = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $content, 1);
    }
    echo $content;
  ?>
```

I was writing a auto link function for my wordpress site and I'm using substr_replace to find the keywords(which are litterally a lot) and replace it with link--I'm doing this by filtering the post content of course.

But in some circumstances, suppose there are posts with titles like "stackoverflow" and "overflow" it turns out to be a mess, the output will look like :

```
 we love<a target="_blank" href="http://www.a.com/stackoverflow">stackoverflow</a>，this is a test。we love <a target="_blank" href="http://www.a.com/stack<a target=" _blank"="">overflow</a> ">stackoverflow，this is a test。
```

What I want is:

```
we love<a target="_blank" href="http://www.a.com/stackoverflow">stackoverflow</a>，this is a test。we love stack<a target="_blank" href="http://www.a.com/overflow">overflow</a>，this is a test。
```

And this is only a test.The production enviorment could be more complicated,like I said there are tens of thousands of titles as  keywords need to be found and replaced with a link. So I see these broken links a lot.It happens when a title contains another title.Like title 'stackoverflow' contains another title 'overflow'.

So my question is how to make substr_replace take title 'stackoverflow' as a whole and replace only once? Of course,'overflow' still needs to be replaced somewhere else just not when it is included in another keyword.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$content` variable is rewritten.

Comment: where is it rewrited? @u_mulder

Comment: can u pls undo your  down vote,I want to save some reputation, thank you:) @u_mulder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent that a search for a word will start replacing inside the HTML code that you already injected for some other word, you could make use of a temporary placeholder, and do the final replacement on those place holders:

```
$titledb = array('经济管理','管理','others');
// sort the array from longer strings to smaller strings, to ensure that 
// a replacement of a longer string gets precedence:
usort($titledb, function ($a,$b){ return strlen($b)-strlen($a); });

$content='经济管理是我们国的家的中心领导力。';

foreach ($titledb as $index => $title) {
    $pos = strpos($content, $title);
    if ($pos !== false) {
        // temporarily insert a place holder in the format '#number#':
        $content = substr_replace($content, "#$index#", $pos, strlen($title));
    }
}

// Now replace the place holders with the final hyperlink HTML code
$content = preg_replace_callback("~#(\d+)#~u", function ($match) use ($titledb) {
    return "<a target='_blank' href='http://www.a.com/{$titledb[$match[1]]}'>{$titledb[$match[1]]}</a>";
}, $content);

echo $content;
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/726636)

Comment: Thank you @trincot,but in this case when there is a second "overflow" shows up it will also be replaced.

Comment: OK, added alternative to my answer which replaces only first occurrences.

Comment: your code works fine in the short example,but when put it in the real condition, it's not replacing anything at all.Pls see the updates.Strange.

Comment: Your update to the question now includes SQL, wordpress API, and functions not defined in the snippet. This overly complicates a question that really only is about the loop. Please provide values for `$titledb` and `$content` with which the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: $titledb is all the post titles which is an array.$titles foreached is really just like $titles in the previous short snippet,only diffrence is that there are now thousands of them. $content is the post content which is also just longer than the preivous $content 'we love stackoverflow，this is an overflow test on stackoverflow。' It's not the loop,it's about filter the post content($content) with the link replacement.

Comment: Yes, it is about the link replacement, which happens in the loop. As you cannot produce an actual case where you have the problem, I cannot help you.

Comment: I'm working on your solution.It seems to be the right one,but it fails on strings in chinese word.\b only match the English words boundary? Thank you.

Comment: So I finally understand why your code works in the snippet but not on my site.It's because the site is using Chinese and I posted the question in English as example.So for a reproduce,pls see this: <?php
  $titledb = array('经济管理','管理','others');
  $content='经济管理是我们国的家的中心领导力。';

  $replace='<a target="_blank" href="http://www.a.com/$1">$1</a>';
  foreach ($titledb as $title) {

      $regex = "~\b(" . preg_quote($title) . ")\b~";
      $content = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $content, 1);
  }
  echo $content;
?>

Comment: The solution is then to add the Unicode modifier to the regular expression (note the `u` at the end: `.....)\b~u`). It is a pity that this is not the default behaviour in PHP.

Comment: Thank you but It's not working with ~u at the end.You can replace the $content and $titeldb with ' $titledb = array('经济管理','管理','others'); $content='经济管理是我们国的家的中心领导力。'; ' and test it.

Comment: I will post a solution, but in the mean time can you update your question and add the information you posted in the last half hour into it? It seems relevant for the question.

Comment: Also, I don't know Chinese, but in the example is there no word break? I see a match at the start of the string, but there is no spacing in the content, so how could an algorithm know it should replace it and is not just a substring of a larger word?

Comment: I just update the code in the question ,you can use it to test. The spacing is just like English,comma ，or a full stop。

Comment: Beside comma and a full stop as sentence spearate, it has spacing also,just look like much smaller than English.

Comment: Well I don't see the spacing or other non-letter after `理`. What am I missing? Do you still want to replace the characters up to that one with a hyperlink so that the next character is `是`?

Comment: Anyway, I rewrote my answer completely using a different approach.

Comment: Awesome! Work like a charm.Thank you so much!